# Como eu faço para que uma variavel se torne objeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter

Model:

```
public function gettoken() {
    $token = $this->db->get('token');
    return $token->result();
```

Controller

```
$this->load->model('Mod_login');
$get = $this->Mode_login->gettoken();
echo $get->datta;
```

Então, queria aprender como faço para a minha variável $get tornasse um objeto para que eu possa pegar os dados do compo da tabela em questão datta. Como faço isso?

Comment: Esqueci de dizer que o echo $get->datta da um erro.
Segue o erro:
Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Esse erro ocorre porque você está tentando acessar uma propriedade de uma variável que não é um objeto. No seu caso essa variável é um array, seja ele vazio ou não, que é o que o método result() retorna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da seguinte forma:

```
$this->load->model('Mod_login');
$get = $this->Mode_login->gettoken();
echo $get[0]->datta;
```

O método `result` do Active Record Class do Codeigniter retorna um array com os resultados do banco de dados em formato de objeto, então você pode acessá-los assim:

```
echo $get[0]->datta;
```

Você poderia deixar seu códido da seguinte forma para acessar o objeto da forma como você quer:

```
$this->load->model('Mod_login');
$listaResultados = $this->Mode_login->gettoken();
$get = $arrayResultado[0];
echo $get->datta;
```

Nesses códigos apresentados acima, certamente pode ocorrer um erro caso não seja retornado nenhum registro do banco de dados e se tente acessar o índice de número 0 do array `$arrayResultado[0]`, então para tratar e resolver assim, você pode apricar a seguinte solução:

```
$this->load->model('Mod_login');
$listaResultados = $this->Mode_login->gettoken();

//Verifica se existe algum elemento no array $listaResultados.
if (count($listaResultados) > 0) {
    $get = $arrayResultado[0];
    echo $get->datta;
}
```

Lembrando que no PHP a tipagem das variáveis são dinâmica, então para uma variável ser tornar um objeto, simplemente atribua um objeto a ela.